# Address to create a contract

Tags: web3js, tokens, contract-deployment, contract-debugging

This query is for informational purposes, with something that has had me in doubt all night.

I am trying to send a self-signed transaction for the creation of a contract

My Tx transaction to send is

```
  const rawTx = {
    nonce:nonce,
    gas:gas,
    from: config.public_key,
    gasPrice:gasPrice,
    to: 0x0,
    chainId: 3,
    data: handle.encodeABI()
  };
```

At the beginning I had the shipping address to create a contract

0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Well, in eth this is the address to create contracts

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Send my transaction with this address, I got the following error.

the contract is not created, but is sent to the address set, when I try to obtain information from the block, I get the following

**"invalid argument 1: json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type hexutil.Uint"**

```
      const status = await this.web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
        signTransaction.rawTransaction
      );
        debugger;
      console.log(status);
      const { data, ...temp } = rawTx;
      const form = {
        transaction: rawTx
      };
      this.config.setConfigContract(form);
      const block= await this.web3.eth.getTransactionFromBlock(status.transactionHash);
```

**status.transactionHash  if it exists
"0x5ae4a37cacbcebd222d3ed48e278266a0e15b06fa83b289d71a8f0122dd12a93"
    https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x5ae4a37cacbcebd222d3ed48e278266a0e15b06fa83b289d71a8f0122dd12a93**

My question is, because using 0x0, or
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, no errors, compared to using "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
Because when I send ethers with the same function in the to field, I put an address in string format,

I use web@1.0.0-beta.35

Comment: `from` should be (public) account address, not public key.

Comment: it's an address, just that it was a typing mistake,
The problem is not the appointment of the variables, but the to field, when it is named as string or number directly.